# Finding pair of values based on condition in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample query on 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20d7b). I need to find pair values (a,1), (c,2) because for them column **SomeCount** have the highest value. Thanks ; )

Comment: whats the required output?

Comment: Required output is  (a,1), (c,2).

Answer (score 1):

```
select SomeName, SerialNo
from testTable
group by SerialNo -- because you want to have the biggest result of SomeCount from a set of rows with the same SerialNo
order by SomeCount DESC -- because you want to have the result with the biggest SomeCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches using joins to get **Group-wise Maximum** rows i assume `SerialNo` as a group

### Approach 1

Using left join

```
select concat(t.SomeName,',',t.SerialNo) pair
,t.*
from testTable t
left join testTable t1 
     on(t.SerialNo = t1.SerialNo
        and t.SomeCount < t1.SomeCount)
WHERE t1.SerialNo IS NULL;
```

### Approach 2

Using inner join with a subselect

```
select concat(t.SomeName,',',t.SerialNo) pair
,t.*
from testTable t
join (select SerialNo ,max(SomeCount) SomeCount 
      from testTable
     group by SerialNo) t1 
on(t.SerialNo = t1.SerialNo  and t.SomeCount = t1.SomeCount)
```

### [`Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20d7b/21)

[**`Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)